# What will be the name of CH2=CH-O-CO-CH3?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

We have this question in the textbook but there is no answer given and I have no idea how to name this compound.

Edit: I tried naming the compound.
Correct me if I am wrong here
1-Methylpropenoate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people would call it vinyl acetate. If you want the systematic name, then it is ethenyl ethanoate.

It is formally derived from "vinyl alcohol" and acetic acid, from which the name follows easily. See here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ester#IUPAC_nomenclature), for example.

The compound is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_acetate.